# Swift truncated label alternative text

Tags: swift, swift3, label, uilabel, truncation

I have two labels in a horizontal stack view controller:

```
labelA.text = "This is text number A"
labelB.text = "This is text number B"
```

they are being truncated:

`[This is... This is...]`

Is there a way to provide the labels with alternate texts to display if it would truncate the original one, like

```
labelA.alternateText = "A"
labelB.alternateText = "B"
```

so it displays

`[A          B         ]`

but would still display the full text for both labels if it could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

1: Add an extension to check if your label is truncated

```
extension UILabel {
    var isTruncated: Bool {
        guard let labelText = text else {
            return false
        }
        let labelTextSize = (labelText as NSString).boundingRect(
            with: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
            context: nil).size

        return labelTextSize.height > bounds.size.height
    }
}
```

2: Add a dictionary to store the original strings

```
var dict = [Int:Any]()
```

3: When you add your labels add tags to them (which will represent the key)

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 50))
label.text = "This is text number A"
label.tag = 0
```

4: Check if the label is truncated, if it is them add a default value and store the original value to your dict:

```
if label.isTruncated {
    dict.updateValue(label.text, forKey: label.tag)
    label.text = "A"
}
```

5: To get back the original value

```
let original = dict[0] // for tag 0 for example
```